# Python - Text Processing

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, text

I am trying to use Python to process text scraped from a `.pdf`.

One of the ways I am trying to do this is: find specific items and print either the same line, the line preceding or the line following.

I have looked around and followed some tutorials that have gotten me to this point but I cannot figure out how to move forward.

The code below will find and print the information from the current line using the "find" function but I need to be able to use it to also print the lines following and before.

The text that is scrapped looks like this:

> Smith, John
>
> Per End 12/12/12
>
> File:
>
> 12345

The code I am using is this:

```
def main():
    file = open("Register.txt","r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        countPerEnd = 0
        countFile = 0
        if line.find("Per End")!=-1:
            countPerEnd = countPerEnd + 1
        if line.find("File:")!=-1:
            countFile = countFile + 1
    print ("Per End: ", countPerEnd)
    print ("File: ", countFile)
main()
```

I can only get what I have to print the lines that are located but need them to be able to fine the other items like in this case the name and number following the "file:".

Since this can be anything but the strings "Per End" and "file:" are always going to be the same.

I printed out the results to see where the output stood.

The output is:
Per End: 12/12/12

and the output I need based on finding "Per End":
Smith, John

Comment: Your question isn't clear.... the text you posted is the input or what you get after you run the function you created? What you wanna do? Extract `Smith, John`, `12/12/12` and `12345` values out of this text?

Comment: I added what the desired results are.  I hope it clears a couple things up.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I can only get what I have to print the lines that are located"*? (Incomprehensible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're trying to do, but I think this should get you on the right tracks:

```
lines = open("register.txt", "r").readlines()

search_counters = {
    "Per End": 0,
    "File:": 0,
}

lines = [line for line in lines if line] # removes empty lines, if there are any
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    for search_key in search_counters.keys():
        if search_key in line:
            search_counters[search_key] += 1
            # print the previous line if the current line contains "Per End":
            if search_key == "Per End":
                print "previous line:", lines[i-1]
```

Comment: So this works well.  But only to a point.  After adding a few more IF statements I get that a certain variable is "not defined" even though it is set up in the Dictionary and everything is coded the same way as the other items.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.